# Error while upgrading sitecore from 7.5 to 8.0

Tags: solr, upgrade

While upgrading sitecore from 7.5 to 8.0.
I am facing following error. It seems to be related to solr. Is there something I am missing here?
[image]

Comment: Please include the exception as text rather than image. Give search engines something to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve this error, download solr support package and add dlls and follow steps to upgrade solr.

You can download this from here - https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/8_0/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_8_0.aspx

This should help you.

Comment: Thanks for quick help. I was right about missing something related to solr. Thanks once again.